# How do you print characters the same way printf prints characters in a while loop?

Tags: c, printf, libc

I am trying to replicate `printf`, however I cannot figure out how to get mine to behave the same way `printf` behaves in a `while` loop.

this is the `while` loop I am using:

```
while (i-- > 0) {
    ft_printf("myprintf");
    ft_putchar('\n');
    printf("realprintf");
    ft_putchar('\n');
}
```

and here is the result

```
myprintf

myprintf

myprintf

myprintf

myprintf

myprintf

myprintf

myprintf

myprintf

myprintf

realprintfrealprintfrealprintfrealprintfrealprintfrealprintfrealprintfrealprintfrealprintfrealprintf%
```

Here is my current `printf`, I'm relatively new so the code is probably really bad and inefficient, comments on it would be greatly appreciated

```
int ft_printf(const char *orgstr, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    char flagprefix;
    int i;

    flagprefix = '%';
    i = 0;
    while(orgstr[i])
    {
        va_start(args, orgstr);
        if(orgstr[i] == flagprefix)
            flag_handler(orgstr[i++], args);
        else
            ft_putchar(orgstr[i]);
        i++;
        va_end(args);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

the `flag_handler` function isn't complete yet, but the example I gave won't call that function anyway.

Comment: is `ft_printf` a function you made up? If so, can you post that function?

Comment: @narusin yea it is, I posted the code I started writing a couple hours ago above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you observe comes from the different buffering mechanisms used by `ft_putchar()` and the real `printf()`. You can fix this by flushing `stdout` at the beginning and end of `ft_printf()` or in between calls in the `while` loop:

```
while (i-- > 0) {
    fflush(stdout);
    ft_printf("myprintf");
    ft_putchar('\n');
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("realprintf");
    fflush(stdout);
    ft_putchar('\n');
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Note that your `ft_printf()` function skeleton has problems:

- You should initialize `args` with `va_start` once before the start of the loop, not for each character in the format string.
- If you pass the `va_list` to a `flag_handler` function, side effects on it may not be reflected back to the caller. You should instead extract the arguments from the variable argument list directly in the `ft_printf()` function.

Here is a modified version:

```
int ft_printf(const char *orgstr, ...) {
    va_list args;
    int i, c;

    va_start(args, orgstr);
    i = 0;
    while ((c = orgstr[i++]) != '\0') {
        if (c == '%') {
            switch (c = orgstr[i++])) {
            case 's':
                ft_putstr(va_arg(args, char *));
                continue;
            /* ... handle other cases ... */
            case '\0':
                break;
            default:
                ft_putchar(c);
                continue;
            }
            break;
        } else {
            ft_putchar(c);
        }
    }
    va_end(args);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the classical buffered stdout. You can call

```
fflush(stdout);
```

at end of your loop to ensure all is sent to the screen.

How did you write your printf version ?

Comment: I submitted the very beginning of my printf above